# One or multiple triggers for a generic Platform Event?

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice, platform-event

**Do Trigger Best Practises still apply with Platform Events?**

With Custom Object `triggers` there are established rules, like:

- Have only one trigger per Object
- Have no logic in the trigger. Instead, delegate to Handler class.

Platform Event Triggers syntactically look the same but seem to work very differently under the hood. Do the above rules still apply, or:

1. Should I keep my triggers isolated and fine-grained like small topic-specific subscriptions?
2. Can I use Trigger frameworks like #fflib where a single Apex class is handling all cases or would this break the isolation and transaction-safety of Platform Events?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is likely to be opinionated. However, my tuppence:

- Personally I see no reason to vary from the approach taken for SObject triggers.
- I would always recommend using separate handler and logic classes for testability.

From a usage perspective, we have so far used platform events to allow us to perform processing that we cannot afford to invoke directly in an SObject trigger, such as initiating queueables or batchables. This approach is taken because platform event triggers *always* run in synchronous mode (so higher limits on numbers of async processes that can be enqueued or executed). Since the trigger behaviour is parameterized via the platform events' content (field values, including specification of class to instantiate) and uses a generic API to initiate the further processing (the class implements the API) we don't see the need for any additional triggers - thereby side-stepping the issue of multiple triggers per event.

I must say, I can't comment on use of fflib's trigger framework since we don't use it.

And to note, again, platform events are [not guaranteed delivery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm):

> In rare cases, the event message might not be persisted in the distributed system during the initial or subsequent attempts. This means that the events aren’t delivered to subscribers, and they aren’t recoverable

We have as yet to see this happen, but it is worth being aware of.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, this is what I do (org has about a dozen `xxx__e` Platform Events)

```
trigger FooTrigger on Foo__e (after insert) {
   PlatformEventsService.toPersistedReceipts(Trigger.new);
}

trigger BarTrigger on Bar__e (after insert) {
   PlatformEventsService.toPersistedReceipts(Trigger.new);
}
```

and `PlatformEventsService.toPersistedReceipts()` basically copies the Platform Event into a Custom `Platform_Event_Receipt__c` object that contains a JSON representation of the incoming data. This ensures the Platform Event gets persisted and limits are never exceeded - even if 2000 events come into the trigger.

All subsequent processing of the Platform Event is done asynchronously and if the async fails (validation rule, record locked, etc) , I write a `DeadLetter__c` pointing at the `Platform_Event_Receipt__c`. This gives me health check dashboards, retry and surveillance capability.

I opted against a domain class for every `xxx__e` but did have service classes for each `xxx__e`